# How to resize objects in pybullet environment?

Tags: robotics, pybullet

I am new to pybullet and i was just trying to render table.
I used the one given as an example on kukaarm. What i wanted to do here is resize it.So i edited the .obj file but this is the result, scaling the mesh in urdf isn't giving me any results. Is there any other way to scale it?[after changing the v values .obj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGzbf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to refer to the soccerball example in the pybullet repo:

https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/examples/soccerball.py

When loading URDF you can set globalScaling parameter.